# steps for invoking webservices in J2ME application

Tags: java, java-me, web-services

I created the J2ME application and I have the web service (developed in Java) that has `HelloServiceNMethod()` as Web method. it returns the `String`. Now i want to invoke this web service in My J2ME MIDlet (in Sun wireless toolkit OR Eclipse)
What steps i have to follow.
Please Guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation you need to read and understand for this can be found:

- In the specifications for JSR-172 at http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=172
- In the JavaME SDK (with example code) at http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/index.jsp
- At the developer support website for your chosen phone manufacturer. i.e. Nokia is at http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Documentation/Java/ (look for Web Services in the Java™ ME Developer's Library). Samsung and Sony Ericsson also have decent documentation and code examples.

The reference implementation of JSR-172, the version phone manufacturers can simply buy outright from Sun and include in their phone, is pure Java. This means that phone manufacturers usually have little reasons to develop their own version of it themselves. Fragmentation should then be minimal.